# Одинаковый вид на всех устройствах

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть 3D игра я хочу, чтобы в неё можно было играть чуть ли не на смарт часах и ТВ только вот проблема в том, что меня волнует вопрос нужно писать какой-то скрипт который бы подстраивал игру под разрешение экрана или сделать минимальное и unity сама подстроет под более высокие разрешения?

А вы в каком разрешении создаёте игры?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, т.к. он слишком общий.

Comment: Вы интересуетесь на тему интерфейса или масштаба самих объектов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вопрос касается обьектов на сцене, то пути целых 3:

1. отдалить камеру в зависимости от разрешения телефона
2. Изменить настройки камеры (угол захвата) в зависимости от разрешения телефона
3. Изменить масштаб всех обьектов на сцене (как по мне, то худший из путей)

Если вопрос касается интерфейса, то все делается чере настройки Канваса. То есть выбрать тип отображения канваса как Screen Overlay, изменить настройки "разрешения канваса", размещать все обьекты с правильно отстроенными констрейнсами и пивот-поинтами.

Comment: А как рассчитать в зависимости от разрешения экрана отдаление камеры?

Comment: Вот что мне ответили на английском Stack Overflow:                                                                                       Если вы имеете в виду ваш фактический игровой режим, вам, вероятно, потребуется написать сценарий, который корректирует FOV камеры в начале игры на основе разрешения, но я не знаю, где начать даже по формуле, которую вы будете использовать.

Comment: ну формально, он ответил более обще. А я дал +- конкретные пути. Подбирать же какой путь тебе удобнее должен ты сам. Как и подбирать формулу по которой расчитывается измение соответственных параметров.